# selenium getXpathCount

Tags: selenium

HI there

selenium.getXpathCount does not find element, any one hoas any idea ? Here is my code:

```
if (existArtist){
int result = selenium.getXpathCount("//*[@id='chugger-results']/div[1]/ul/li").intValue();
  if (result>0){

//DO THIS
```

Comment: I am sorry but there is no where near enough info to help

Comment: Could you post your xml data?

Comment: It would be great to provide a better explanation of what you are trying to do. The code posted does not give much context and as such  nobody would be able to provide you with the needed help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you have a broken DOM (Do a W3C Validation and see if you have any unclosed tags) or your XPath is looking for an element that doesn't exist.

We would need to see the entire HTML of the page to be able to answer your question (more visibility of your test code would be useful too)